# Disallow Source Code Editing in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm using some templates to work around some use cases in mediawiki and if an untrained user edits these templates my site functionality breaks in some places.

I want the users to be able to edit some sites with [this extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms), but if they edit the source code of the template the functionality breaks.

Is there a way to disallow users or disable the source code editing for mediawiki entries or set rules for user groups to disallow source editing? Is it still possible for the users to edit the pages with the form editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to modify the edit page via a hook like https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/EditPage::showEditForm:fields

By removing inputs or making fields readonly and adding a notification to use the form, you should be able to get a situation where pages are not editable vie the edit page directly. I'm not sure if that would affect form editing though.